# GitHub API response with fewer files

Tags: python, python-requests, github-api, pull-request

I am new to GitHub API.
I am writing a Python program (using *requests*) that should list all the changed/added files of a pull request in a given repository.

Using the API I am able to list all the pull requests and get their numbers. However, when I try to get the information about the files, the response does not contain all the files in the pull request.

```
pf = session.get(f'https://api.github.com/repos/{r}/pulls/{pull_num}/files')
pj = pf.json()
pprint.pprint(pf.json())
for i in range(len(pj)):
    print(fj[i]['filename']))
```

*(I know there might be a prettier way, Python is not really my cup of coffee yet, but when I compare the `pf.text` with the output of this snippet, the result is identical.)*

I know that there is a limit of **300 files** as mentioned in the documentation, but the problem occurs even if their total number is less that 300.

I created a test repo with a single pull request that adds files called *file1, file 2, ..., file222* and after I send the GET request, the response only contains filenames of:

file1, file10, file100, file101, file102, file103, file104, file105, file106, file107, file108, file109, file11, file110, file111, file112, file113, file114, file115, file116, file117, file118, file119, file12, file120, file121, file122, file123, file124, file125

Is there another limit that I don't know about? Or why would the response contain only those filenames? How do I get all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution a while after I posted the question. The API sends a few entries (filenames) and a link to another page in the header of the response. The files from the question are the first few in the alphabetical order, the first page.